# Rails application with pusher/faye

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, faye

Iv'e been asked to make an app like this one: http://www.dealcent.com/

Im having trouble figuring out how to make the bids update, i think that i could use something like pusher or faye (http://pusher.com/ or http://faye.jcoglan.com/) and subscribe to each event. but i was wondering if there was a more elegant/efficient solution.

also if it could be hosted on heroku or would it be better a private VPN.

It has to be on rails 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used pusher with much success, not sure about faye since I never used it. We use pusher to push responses from asynchronous background jobs to the user when those jobs are done.

It's quite nifty and takes very little setup.

Comment: But do you think it is optimal to use it in the app scenario I describe?

Comment: Certainly, have the user subscribe to a user specific channel and then push from the server whenever something needs to be updated on the client. Depending on the number of visitors and how frequently you expect bids to change of course. I mean with enough traffic it might get expensive even though pusher is kind of decently priced.